# how to validate first place is decimal only in vb?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I want to validate a textbox if it is taking only decimal in first place. no 0 or any number (ex: .5 not 0.5) Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can always test the left-most character to be Chr(46). IMHO, it would be better to use something like Instr to test for the existence of a Chr(46) in the final entry and use Mid to truncate anything left of that point.

Answer (score 0):

I took textbox named TextBox1 and a button named Button1 wrote the following code on click event of Button1:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim getstr As String = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 1)
        If getstr = "." Then
            MsgBox("Your input's first place is a '.' - validated.")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: should check the length of `Textbox1.Text` to be greater than or equal to 1 (or just greater than 0), or put a try catch around the function (if user doesn't input anything and clicks the button it'll throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. Other than that nice and simple.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this function...

```
Private Function do_validate(ByRef curr_textbox As TextBox) As Boolean
    Dim to_return As Boolean = False

    Try
        Dim curr_input_text As String = curr_textbox.Text

        If (Len(curr_input_text > 0)) Then
            Dim left_most As String = Mid(curr_input_text, 1, 1)
            If left_most = "." Then
                to_return = True
            End If
        End If

    Catch
    Finally
        Select Case to_return
            Case True
                curr_textbox.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
            Case False
                curr_textbox.BackColor = Color.LightPink
        End Select
    End Try

    Return to_return
End Function
```

And then it can be called from the TextBox.TextChanged event like this do_validate(txt_input). It could also be called from a submit button as part of a validation sequence.